# There is a time and/or date difference between the client and server

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, jenkins

I am running a Build Job using Jenkins. The Jenkins job executes a command shown below that simply copies a test file from server A to server B.  Jenkins resides on Server A and well as the command file. The Servers are running Windows Server 2008 R2.

```
copy C:\Users\myuser\test.txt" "\\ServerB\myfolder\test.txt"
```

The command fails with the error message:

> There is a time and/or date difference between the client and
>   server.

Jenkins uses the Windows account *myuser*. If you log onto ServerA as *myuser* and run the command, it works just fine.

The System Admin ran the command [w32tm /resync](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307897) on both servers. No effect.

If I change the command to copy to Server C instead, it works fine from Jenkins.

Tried rebooting Server B, no luck.

The times and timezones on the servers all look the same down to the second.

Any ideas on how to fix this this?

Answer (score 1):

1 command:

```
net time /set
```

...on both the workstation and server.  This will ensure that both have the proper time/date set (make sure time zones are set properly.  Just because it says 4PM in the tray... does not mean 4PM in YOUR timezone.)

Answer (score 1):

Our Sys. Admin fixed this for us. Here were the steps:

1. Ran: [w32tm /resync](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307897)
2. [Disabled User Access Control](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2526083). He did this by selecting **Start > Run > msconfig > Tools > Change UAC Settings** and lowering it to the **Never Notify setting**.
3. **Rebooted**. Then the problem went away.

Comment: I was getting this error during a powershell remote session script and the only thing I had to do fix it was run the 1st command. I didn't even restart my powershell session and it immediately fixed the problem